# Build gradle assemble apk using laravel function

Tags: python, android, linux, gradle, laravel-5

I'm currently calling the main python file in larval function, and inside that main python file I'm calling another 2 files ( PowerShell and sub python file) the problem is when the Laravel function is triggered it only call the main python file, however when I call the main python file using terminal all the files are executed like below:

**Laravel function:**

```
public function initialize(Request $request)
{
    $store_name = $request->get('store_name', 1);
    if (empty($store_name)) {
        return 'Missing store name';
    } else {
        $processes = File::get("/root/flask/android_api/processes.txt");
            File::put('/root/flask/android_api/url.txt', $store_name );
            $process = new Process(['python3.6', '/root/flask/android_api/buildAPK.py']);
            $process->run();
            if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
                    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
            } else {
                    return 'Starting the processes to build';
            }   
    } 
}
```

**and within the main python file I have:**

```
try:
    p = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/pwsh", 
            "/root/flask/android_api/set_apk_builder.ps1", '-ExecutionPolicy',
                        'Unrestricted',
                        './buildxml.ps1'], 
            stdout=sys.stdout)
    p.communicate()

except:
    file = open ("/root/flask/android_api/log.txt", "w")
    file.write ("fail")
    file.close()


import slack
  //  call(["python", "/root/flask/flask.py"])
    os.system('python3.7 /root/flask/flask.py')
```

---

**Edit:**

now I changed the build to be direct from laravel function to generate the apk
using this command:

```
public function initialize(Request $request)
{
    $store_name = $request->get('store_name', 1);
    if (empty($store_name)) {
        return 'Missing store name';
    } else {
            return shell_exec('cd /var/www/html/androidProject && chmod +x gradlew && ./gradlew assembledemoDebug');
    }
     
}
```

however, the command line returns the Gradle command build is starting but it doesn't create a folder and generate the apk

the Current folder structure /var/www/html and inside html is the project folder and laravel project

note: before I call Gradle build command inside Laravel function, I used to call python file and that python file is calling Gradle command but I had the same issue the apk is not created, but when I run the same python file from bash command it works fine

Comment: first run without `try/except` to see full error mesage.

Comment: why do you run `flask.py` two times? first `call`, next `os.system`?  BTW: you use module `flask` so better don't use word `flask` as script name and folder name because later `import flask` may try to load your script/folder instead of module `flask`

Comment: i did try without try and except at start but nothing happened, also calling flask.py two times was mistake when i coped the code i was testing both ways but i removed comments before asking questions, the question is updated now with comment on one

Comment: if it doesn't change then maybe you should save in file/log informatio every few lines to see which line was executed. Maybe it shows what can be the problem. If you don't get any information then we have no clue what is the problem and we can't help.

Comment: @furas question is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can accomplish this:

The first is to include your commands into a .sh file that you should make it executable using this command:

> chmod +x file.sh

Then you should call that file from laravel using Symfony process so you can get details of the log process and errors:

> use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
> use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;

```
$process = new Process('sh /folder_name/file_name.sh');

$process->run();
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}
echo $process->getOutput();
```

Then include all commands in that file you wish to run.

Second you can run those commands using

```
$output = shell_exec('ls -lart');
then echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

You'll need to move all your writable files into public directory in Laravel, because that's where everything should be editable.'=

I actually suggest the first one as you don't need to change owner of some folders to www-data to give write permissions.